# System.DllNotFoundException on Mono SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, dllnotfoundexception

I've been trying to figure this out lately. It is working on my Windows machine, where I got SQLite from NuGet, but...

When I put `System.Data.SQLite.dll` and `SQLite.Interop.dll` straight from my Windows machine into Linux server it says that `SQLite.Interop.dll` is not found, but I am sure I see it next right to executable.

Then I tried to compile `System.Data.SQLite.dll` with `/p:UseInteropDll=false`, but with no luck. This time it says that `System.Data.SQLite.dll` is not found.

What is this "not found" mystery?

Comment: Lile user3791372 said, turns out that you need to build System.Data.SQLite under Linux as there is no pre-build binaries to download - you can find the detailed instructions in this article: http://blog.wezeku.com/2016/10/09/using-system-data-sqlite-under-linux-and-mono/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Mono.Data.SQLite.dll` on Linux. Take a look at the Mono manual to [using SQLite on Linux](http://www.mono-project.com/SQLite) or [build the System.Data.SQLite.dll on Mono](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/build.wiki#mono).

You can also map the DLL:

```
<configuration>
  <dllmap dll="sqlite" target="libsqlite.so.0" os="linux"/>
  <dllmap dll="sqlite" target="libsqlite.0.dylib" os="osx"/>
  <dllmap dll="sqlite3" target="libsqlite3.so.0" os="linux"/>
  <dllmap dll="sqlite3" target="libsqlite3.0.dylib" os="osx"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not a useful solution when the application is supposed to run on both Mono and .NET.

Comment: The is a way to map  differently on each  platform, just deploy a different .config file for each platform

Comment: @Alexandre Marcondes, Our application is supposed to run on both Mono and .NET. How do we deploy a different .config file for Mono and .NET on Ubuntu Linux? Thank you.

Comment: How do you map the DLLs? where do you put that snippet?

Answer (score 12):

No code changes necessary. You can build it yourself.

1. `apt-get install build-essentials unzip`
2. Download the SQLITE source code - you want the full source code. Currently called [sqlite-netFx-full-source-1.0.104.0.zip](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).
3. `unzip` and `cd Source`,
4. `chmod +x` the `compile-interop-assembly-release.sh` build shell script, then run it `./compile-interop-assembly-release.sh`. - It'll build an `.so` file in the `../bin` directory.
5. Copy this `.so` file to the directory that has your application in
6. Run your application as normal.
7. Note: Ensure that your SQLite database and the directory it's inside of are writable by the user you're trying to run as.

Comment: are there some other configuration settings we need to change? Im still getting the same error

Comment: On macOS, I noticed that copying the built `libSQLite.Interop.dylib` file (equivalent of the `.so` file on Linux) into the application directory may not work. Instead I'm copying `libSQLite.Interop.dylib` directly into `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries/`

Comment: Hi, When I do that and try to launch the app I get a : "System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named "sqlite3_key" in DLL "sqlite3"" Do you know why ?

Comment: I tried this, built without problems, version exactly matches my NuGet package version, and I get System.EntryPointNotFoundException: SIa069da76968b7553 which is... OK so the entry point is a hash? If they wanted to make it as difficult as possible, they succeeded.

Answer (score 6):

I started the development in Windows, but then moved the application to Mono (Ubuntu 14), which is where the SQLite provider failed to load as OP described.

I had to recompile the System.Data.SQLite.dll using the following command:

```
MSBuild System.Data.SQLite.2012.csproj /t:Rebuild /p:UseInteropDll=false /p:UseSqliteStandard=true
```

However, after this I've got the following exception:

> The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance.
>   Method `System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods:GetSettingValue (string,string)' is inaccessible from method`System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderManifest:GetProviderManifestToken (string)'

To fix this, I had to recompile the System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll using the following command:

```
MSBuild System.Data.SQLite.EF6.2012.csproj /t:Rebuild /p:UseInteropDll=false /p:UseSqliteStandard=true
```

After copying all of the generated files to Mono project's bin directory, everything worked.

The SQLite provider source code version I had used was 1.0.98.1.

Hope this saves someone a lot of time...

Comment: This worked for me. Don't forget to build in Release mode with /p:Configuration=Release at the end. Building EF6 wasn't necessary for me and didn't compile anyway. First I tried compiling libSQLite.Interop.on the server so but never got that to work. Now it works. However, there are "unclear drawbacks" to not using the interop library. Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the above option but those options could not solve SQLite DLL problem, It may be because I am using ubuntu 18 version, So tried other option and here the steps,

1) Download SQLite source code from the https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.111.0/sqlite-netFx-full-source-1.0.111.0.zip

2) unzip source code and **cd to unzip directory**

3) Run  the following command in the terminal,

xbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:UseInteropDll=false /p:UseSqliteStandard=true ./System.Data.SQLite/System.Data.SQLite.2010.csproj

4) Above command would create a dll file at following path,

sqlite-netFx-full-source-1.0.111.0/bin/2010/ReleaseMonoOnPosix/bin

5) Copy System.Data.SQLite.dll to your project bin folder.

6) Clean project and build again.

I hope this would help.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with [System.Data.SQLite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/) 1.0.109 you don't need to compile anything yourself since the native `SQLite.Interop.dll` files are included in the NuGet package for all platforms (Linux, macOS and Windows). Note that although the `dll` extension is used for all platforms, the files are actually native dynamic libraries (usually suffixed *dylib* on macOS and *so* on Linux).

```
$ find ~/.nuget/packages/system.data.sqlite.core/1.0.111/runtimes -name SQLite.Interop.dll -print0 | xargs -0 file
…/runtimes/linux-x64/native/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.dll: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=96ce4120b31bad7d95f7b9ccf7c4bbb7717ae0b1, with debug_info, not stripped
…/runtimes/osx-x64/native/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.dll:   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
…/runtimes/win-x86/native/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.dll:   PE32 executable (DLL) (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
…/runtimes/win-x64/native/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.dll:   PE32+ executable (DLL) (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

Unfortunately, the MSBuild target responsible for copying the native dynamic libraries into the output directory only works on Windows. This is probably because the authors of the package assumed that .NET Framework only runs on Windows, which is not true thanks to Mono.  Also, if you wanto to have a look, the `CopySQLiteInteropFiles` target can be found in `~/.nuget/packages/system.data.sqlite.core/{version}/build/net4*/System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets`.

But it's possible to automatically copy the `SQLite.Interop.dll` file into the output directory on Linux and macOS. Add the `FixSQLiteInteropFilesOnLinuxAndOSX` target (described below) in your csproj file and you'll be able to use System.Data.SQLite.Core on Linux and macOS running mono without the `DllNotFoundException`. Here's how your project should look like:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="FixSQLiteInteropFilesOnLinuxAndOSX" BeforeTargets="CopySQLiteInteropFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <SQLiteInteropFiles Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform(Linux)) OR $([MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform(OSX))" Remove="@(SQLiteInteropFiles)" />
      <SQLiteInteropFiles Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform(Linux))" Include="$(PkgSystem_Data_SQLite_Core)/runtimes/linux-x64/native/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.*" />
      <SQLiteInteropFiles Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform(OSX))" Include="$(PkgSystem_Data_SQLite_Core)/runtimes/osx-x64/native/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.111" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Make sure to add [`GeneratePathProperty="true"`](https://blog.dangl.me/archive/accessing-nuget-package-paths-in-your-net-sdk-based-csproj-files/) in the package reference. This is required for the `PkgSystem_Data_SQLite_Core` property to be defined.

Comment: I'm looking at NuGet packaging release 1.0.115, and it includes...x86 and x64. (Now in the Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core... package) So much for linux or docker deployments. :(

Comment: Indeed, the NuGet packaging changed in recent versions of System.Data.SQLite. You can adapt the answer and use the `Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetStandard` package and `$(PkgStub_System_Data_SQLite_Core_NetStandard)` instead of `System.Data.SQLite.Core` to get the references to the SQLite.Interop.* files.