# entity framework with sqlite on mono

Tags: c#, linux, entity-framework, sqlite, mono

I have been trying to connect to a sqlite database in an mvc web app on linux using mono for a while now and I havent been able to get it to work. At first I kept getting the `System.DLLNotFoundException` because it couldn't find `SQLite.Interop.dll` for some reason. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21294288/5415895) I'm supposed to use `Mono.Data.Sqlite` on linux instead of `System.Data.SQLite`.

I was able to connect to the database using `Mono.Data.Sqlite` in a test console application without using the Entity Framework, but whenever I try to use Entity Framework I get the error

```
The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteFactory, Mono.Data.Sqlite, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' did not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'.
```

Is it possible to use the Entity Framework with SQLite on Mono? Are there any tutorials for it?